# CRM 2015 - Form Onload Error

Tags: javascript, crm

I have a strange problem in CRM 2015 on-premise.
Recently I started to get errors on form onload of Price List Item (ProductPriceLevel).
No javascript source was set in the form properties.

EDIT:
I fixed the problem by editing the customization.xml and added those fields manually.

Comment: What kind of errors? Believe me, it is not easy to read your mind...

Comment: Sorry, tried to upload an image but cannot. I get "There was an error with this field's customized event. Error: Unable to get property 'setDisabled' of undefined or null reference".    Again i remind you that there is no JS on the form property.  Thanks

Comment: I found out that the field "Percentage" is not on the form (used for the Pricing Method field). The field is exist in the entity solution fields list but cannot add it to the form again... Tried to Import this entity from other environment but nothing get changes... How can i add this field? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit in a link to the image if you have it uploaded elsewhere. Me or some other user with high enough reputation can edit it to display for you.

Comment: Hi, the worng form: http://s9.postimg.org/qm833jpxb/worng_Form.png

Comment: The onLoad error: http://postimg.org/image/hsvk3a5rz/
The onChange error : http://postimg.org/image/kokajjr0h/
the problem is that the field of percentage is missing and i can't add it back to the form.